# Text whithin 1 column following a criteria, separated by ;

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to reduce rows in an excel since I have repetetive data for all the columns/variables, except for 1 column - "link_id"

I have this:

```
A kk   323  11  44 linkA
A kk   323  11  44 linkB
A pp   444  22  88 linkZ
```

I would like this:

```
A kk   323  11  44 linkA; linkB
A pp   444  22  88 linkZ
```

```
data_file = pd.read_excel("entrada.xlsx")
red = data_file["RED"]
tipus = data_file["TIPUS"]
label = data_file["Label"]
idnode = data_file["IDNode"]
agrupacio = data_file["AGRUPACIO"]
sumofshape = data_file["SumOfShape_Area"]
sumofarea = data_file["SumOfAREA_NETA"]
minofnode = data_file["MinOfNOD_PDinamica"]
nodQ = data_file["NOD_Q"]
link_id = data_file["link_id"]

my_data =[red, tipus, label, idnode, agrupacio, sumofshape, sumofarea, minofnode, nodQ, link_id]
df = pd.concat(my_data, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dummy columns names, and letting df denote your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',  'kk',   '323',  '11',  '44',  'linkA' ],
['A',  'kk',   '323',  '11',  '44',  'linkB' ],
['A',  'pp',   '444',  '22',  '88',  'linkZ' ]])
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'link_id']
```

Assuming you want all the data to match before combining links:

```
def col_to_list(df): 
        df['link_id2'] = [df['link_id'].tolist()]*len(df)
        return df

df = df.groupby([i for i in df.columns if i not in 'link_id']).apply(lambda df: col_to_list(df))
df = df.drop(columns = ['link_id']).drop_duplicates(subset= [i for i in df.columns if i not in 'link_id2']).reset_index(drop = True)
df
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   link_id2
0   A   kk  323 11  44  [linkA, linkB]
1   A   pp  444 22  88  [linkZ]
```